# How to use a measure as an axis in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a query that I call "cuartil" which I want to work as an axis. If I put it in a table it would show like this:

[image]

then this measure may vary according to the region filter that is made, as for example in this image:

[image]

but I want to show it in a graph, in which I would like to use the measure as an axis, but the power bi does not allow me to use it as such

Will there be any way to put a measure as an axis?

To obtain the "cuartil" measure, first calculate the UniqueRank:

```
UniqueRank = 
RANKX (
  tabla_ranking;
  FORMAT ( tabla_ranking[nro_trabajos]; "0000" ) & tabla_ranking[region] & 
tabla_ranking[site]
)
```

then I calculate the measure ranking2:

```
ranking2 = 
RANKX (
   ALLSELECTED ( tabla_ranking );
   tabla_ranking[UniqueRank];
   MAX ( tabla_ranking[UniqueRank] )
)
```

and finally calculate the measure "cuartil"

```
  cuartil = IF(tabla_ranking[ranking2]<= 
    [total_registros]*0.25;"1P";IF(tabla_ranking[ranking2]<= 
    [total_registros]*0.5;"2P";IF(tabla_ranking[ranking2]<= 
    [total_registros]*0.75;"3P";"4P")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a measure for an axis. However, if `cuartil` is not dependent on a slicer or any dynamic filtering, then you can create a calculated column using the measure and use the calculated column for your axis.

---

To use `cuartil` on an axis, create a new table `Axis` with the column:

```
cuartil
----
1P
2P
3P
4P
```

Then you can write measures to use for your graph. For example,

```
numero trabajos = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( tabla_ranking[nro_trabajos] ),
    FILTER ( tabla_ranking, [cuartil] IN VALUES ( Axis[cuartil] ) )
)
```

Comment: in my case the measure depends on a region filter

Comment: @Kevincs7 That doesn't look to be the case in your example. All the values are the same between the first and second image (the `CENTRO` ones are just filtered out).

Comment: they are not the same, LI6241_PALMERAS in the first image is 1P and in the second image it is 2P,

Comment: @Kevincs7 Ah, you are right. Can you edit in the code for your measure into your question?

Comment: excellent alexis, now if I can do what I'm looking for. although I have one more query, what happens is that when I had my static graph, I put in the axis the column "cuartil" and also in the lower part of the same axis, I added the column "site". then when I double clicked on the bar, the sites that belonged to that quartile came out. Will there be any way that the same can happen with your code?

Comment: I think you'd need to ask a separate question about that. It's a bit beyond the scope of this one.

Comment: this is the link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963624/how-to-use-the-detailed-mode-in-a-power-bi-graphic