# PowerBi - Set Axis Maximum as a measure

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to be able to set the maximum on my Y axis for a visual based on a calculated measure.
For example, if i have a measure which is max number of steps covered for a group, and i want this to be the maximum on y scale so it remains dynamic to changes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

With the power bi visuals it is not possible to directly use a measure on the axis.
There are a number of workarounds using a calculated column and IF statements to create a column that can be use. [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56956190/how-to-use-a-measure-as-an-axis-in-power-bi) and [Power BI Community](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Use-Measure-as-Axis-in-visual/td-p/134569)

One other alternative would be to use a R visual, they are able to take a measure and apply it to an axis